# "To be starved" for "to be hungry, starving" in colloquial AE

Tags: colloquialisms

Is "to be starved" a typical AE expression for "to be starving"?

> I'm starved! What's for breakfast? [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=wnt484lg9koC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=%22i%27m+starved+what%27s%22&source=bl&ots=DThyIyxyv6&sig=L5jxqc1WYqySSFCt3AIZGgwnuDI&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=c80lU_z7Auit0QXG04HQBw&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22i%27m%20starved%20what%27s%22&f=false)
>
> I'm starved. What's for dinner? [source](http://www.princetonlibrary.org/blog/2012/07/fast-and-simple-takes-gold?page=1)
>
> I'm starved. When do we eat? [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=Miq7Y7YmB_UC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=%22i%27m+starved+when%22&source=bl&ots=alxpjvdURe&sig=bRfp6om6cgeGfEqux3tJHl9wdbc&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=As8lU7TDEsPG0QXyjoCAAw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=%22i%27m%20starved%20when%22&f=false)

Comment: It would depend on whether and how one differentiates *starved* and *starving*, and I don't think that is done any differently in any of the varieties of English with which I am familiar.

Comment: The question seemed clear enough to me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I've heard Americans say 'I'm starved', meaning 'I'm starving'.